# Mouse drag to scroll content

Tags: jquery, transform, drag

I'm currently working on a gallery where you drag to scroll trough the images in the gallery, something similar to [this](http://weareanonymous.fr/projects/happy-64).

The drag detection is working fine, but I don't get the sliding of the content to work properly. It detects the dragging and manages to set the proper position, but it jumps back to the beginning when I drag again.

This is how the function that runs on drag looks like:

```
dragContent: function(e) {

    var delta = e.pageX - Project.dragStartX;
    Project.isIE ? $('#gallery-content').css("margin-left", delta) : $('#gallery-content').css("translateX", delta);

},
```

Have a look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh15a64y/1/) were I have recreated the problem.

I think I need to save the position where the content stops and somehow start from that position on the next drag detected. I also want the smooth easing like the example, were it still rolls for a bit on "mouseup".

I'm hoping that someone want to share their thoughts on how to solve this without using plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to store the current state of the slider. Right now, you're correctly calculating the delta, which is the distance your mouse (or pointer) has traveled. Then you're setting the delta as margin, meaning that you always start at 0.

I modified your code, you can find a [solution in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n96mqbo/).

In addition to your dragStartX, i also introduced a containerX and tempContainerX

```
// beginning of the code
dragStartX = 0;
containerX = 0;
tempContainerX = 0;
```

on mousedown, i update containerX (which is "where the box started")

```
containerX = containerX + tempContainerX;
```

on drag, i will use this initial offset to correct the position:

```
$('#gallery-content').css("margin-left",containerX + delta);
```

Comment: Sweet, this is working great. Is there a way I can prevent the content to scroll further than it's length, so it will stop when it reaches one of the ends?

Comment: left border is easy: just make sure, that you never go OVER 0 (as margin will push the item to the right, revealing the background. EDIT: first part is here: https://jsfiddle.net/3zdd94xy/

Comment: right border is essentially the same, you'd have to make sure that you never go BELOW `- sliderwidth + viewportwidth`

Answer (score 0):

To get jank-free dragging, you will need to keep track of the element's existing `margin-left` at the time of `mousedown` and add to it instead of overwriting it. Following is a live example that uses a new variable "marginLeftStart" to keep track of what the original `margin-left` was on mouse down.

**Working Live Example:**

```js
//Set Variables
var enableDrag = false,
    dragStartX = 0;
var marginLeftStart = 0;

// Enable dragging and set position on mousedown
$('#gallery-container').mousedown(function(e) {

    enableDrag = true;
    dragStartX = e.pageX;

    marginLeftStart = parseInt($('#gallery-content').css("margin-left"));

    e.preventDefault();
});

// set position of content if dargging is enabled.
$(document).unbind("mousemove");
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

    if (enableDrag) {

        // Get the position of the drag. 
        var delta = e.pageX - dragStartX;

        // Set the css. 
        $('#gallery-content').css("margin-left", marginLeftStart + delta);
    }

    e.preventDefault();

});

// Disable dragging on "mouseup".
$(document).unbind("mouseup");
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

    if (enableDrag) {
        enableDrag = false;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

```css
#gallery-container {
 height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#gallery-content {
    float: left;
    width: 1650px;
}
.gallery-item {
    float: left;
}

.gallery-item img {
    border: 0;
 max-width: none;
 height: 300px;
 width: auto;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery-container">
    <div id="gallery-content">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x500/000000/fff&text=Dummyimage 1" />
        </div>
         <div class="gallery-item">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/450x500/000000/fff&text=Dummyimage 2" />
        </div>       
        <div class="gallery-item">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x500/000000/fff&text=Dummyimage 3" />
        </div>    
        <div class="gallery-item">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x500/000000/fff&text=Dummyimage 4" />
        </div>         
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/uh15a64y/3/